# About P-value for ARIMA in R

Tags: time-series, arima

I know I could obtain $p$-value by calculating coef/standard error using R command `pnorm()`.

When the $p$-value of each coefficient is less than 0.05 
(confidence interval 95%), can I reject those coefficients?

For example, given these $p$-value:

```
ar1: 0.003
ar2: 0.432
ar3: 0.04
```

do I have to reject `ar2` and run my analysis again?
Or, since the last $p$-value of `ar3` is less than 0.05, can I accept all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the p-value of parameters for ARIMA model in R?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8868/how-to-calculate-the-p-value-of-parameters-for-arima-model-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't have to reject any parameter estimates; that's an option.  Often, and without nearly as much justification as there ought to be  (well, without any justification at all in many cases), people will say "if the p-value > 0.05, I'll set the coefficient equal to zero; otherwise, I'll use the estimated value."  This is not always a good thing to do, but that discussion should be attached to a different question.

More to the point of *your* question, though, if you were to adopt such a rule, you'd rerun the analysis, leaving out the ar2 term.  The p-value only applies to the specific coefficient to which it is attached; it's not cumulative with respect to all the previous coefficients.