# How to get p-values for model

Tags: r, time-series

I am using the example from Shumway's book. How do I get the p-values for all the coefficients? Do I divide the coeffients by the standard errors?

```
 Call:
    arima(x = cmort, order = c(2, 0, 0), xreg = cbind(trend, temp, temp2, part))

    Coefficients:
             ar1     ar2  intercept    trend     temp   temp2    part
          0.3848  0.4326  3075.1482  -1.5165  -0.0190  0.0154  0.1545
    s.e.  0.0436  0.0400   834.7157   0.4226   0.0495  0.0020  0.0272

    sigma^2 estimated as 26.01:  log likelihood = -1549.04,  aic = 3114.07
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the p-value of parameters for ARIMA model in R?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8868/how-to-calculate-the-p-value-of-parameters-for-arima-model-in-r)

Comment: But in the book, Shumway says that trend is not significant. I am not sure how he got the conclusion

Comment: See the function listed in this [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-June/202173.html).

Comment: @phil12 If he got the same trend and s.e. that you did, it seems a surprising thing to say; it looks significant to me.

Comment: may be it was a typo in the book...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try bootstrapping your data (i.e. sample your data with replacement), and then re-fit your model to the bootstrapped data. This should give you an idea of how stable the fitted trends are, and whether or not they are significant. (For example, when you repeat this procedure, if one trend comes out positive over 97.5% of the time, then you could consider the trend to be significant.)