# Z test of coefficients of output?

Tags: r, probability, p-value, arma

I have fitted a certain ARMA model and got the following output:

[image: sp]

As you can see, some coeff were set to zero and the focus is on the ma5 coeff and the intercept. To be exactly, the ma5 coeff is  `-0.05077979`  and the intercept is `-0.00044509`. Also the exact s.e. are `0.02078887` (ma5) and `0.00032599` (intercept). I want to calculate the p-values:

From the answer [with 7 thumbs up on this thread (from mpiktas)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8868/how-to-calculate-the-p-value-of-parameters-for-arima-model-in-r) I calculated it with:

```
(1-pnorm(abs(-0.05077979)/sqrt(0.02078887^2)))/2
```

which should give me the p-value for the ma5 coeff, and the output is

```
0.003645037
```

For the intercept I do

```
(1-pnorm(abs(-0.00044509)/sqrt(0.00032599^2)))/2
```

and get

```
 0.04303588
```

Now I control this via coeff test of the lmtest package:

```
library(lmtest)
coeftest(myarmamodel)
```

and I get

[image: ot]

As you can see, the estimates and the s.e. are the same, but the p-value is different. My question is: Why? What is wrong? Is the p-value of the lmtest wrong or the solution in the other post?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the $z$-value in lmtest is simply the ratio of the estimate and its corresponding standard error. This is exactly what mpiktas described in the post that you linked (the one with 7 thumbs up). So, for example: $z_{ma5}=-0.05078/0.02079 = -2.443$. Then, the CDF of the standard normal distribution is used to calculate the two-sided p-value:

```
2*pnorm(-2.443) = 0.0146
```

or if you use the other/upper tail of the distribution

```
2*(1-pnorm(2.443)) = 0.0146
```

which is the p-value provided by `lmtest`. The solution of `lmtest` is straightforward and well-known, so nothing wrong with that.

I honestly don't know why mpiktas *divides* the value by 2 instead of multiplying it, which seems to be the correct way (**EDIT:** it was a mistake. Fixed in the original answer of mpiktas).

Your caluclated p-values by the method of mpiktas are therefore 4 times smaller than the ones calculated by `lmtest`: `4*0.003645037 = 0.0146`.